# recognizing and dealing with 2 valid paths when walking a hex map

Tags: php, dictionary, hexagonal-tiles

I am writing a cost path script for use on hexagonal maps. Currently I am in the "learning how to walk" phase of development.

In general terms the code works. I can reliably get from A to B. However, consider the following map:

[image]

Both the sequence `0406 -> 0405 -> 0505` and `0406 -> 0506 -> 0505` are valid. I would like to traverse and output BOTH paths.

My code follows:

```
public function walkMap($origCol, $origRow, $destCol, $destRow) {
    $curRow = $origRow;
    $curCol = $origCol;
    while (($curRow != $destRow) || ($curCol != $destCol)) {
        $newRow = self::getNextMove($curRow,$destRow);
        if ($newRow == $curRow) {
            $curCol = self::getNextMove($curCol,$destCol);
        } else {
            $curRow = $newRow;
        }
    }
}

private function getNextMove($cur,$dest) {
    if ($cur < $dest) {
        ++$cur;
    } else if ($cur > $dest) {
        --$cur;
    }
    return $cur;
}
```

My desired result is a numeric array of `step => hexCoord` showing the path taken. But I'm not sure how to adopt the above working code to intelligently branch, and having done that, how best to shape the output data structure...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the path `0406 -> 0507 -> 0506 -> 0505` not valid because it is longer than the others? Do you only want to search the shortest paths?

Comment: @Basti - yes, shortest path always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that, at the moment, your path choice is simply "get to the right row, then get to the right column." I realize that you're still getting started, but you might want to think ahead about how you want to work cost into your paths and let that tell you about your data structure.

For example, you can use [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to mark each point on your map with the least cost from that point to a given destination. Finding a path is then a matter of picking an origin and repeatedly moving to the neighboring hex with the least cost, building the path array that you want as you go. If there are two optimal paths at any point, you'll see that as a hex with two minimally-cheap neighbors -- you'd make a new copy of the path array for each and complete them independently. Taking that approach, you'd work with (and return) an array of path arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I used two Classes: Cubicles which are those hexagonal things that got a column and a row number, and Paths which are a ordered list of Cubicles. Cubicles have a function branch to get all Cubicles, that are in the "right direction" on the path to destination. and directly reachable from the Cubicle by just doing one step.

i then start with the path of length 1 (only the start) and steadily expand this path by all branches, producing one path for each branch, which is 1 longer, than the old. if it can not be expanded anymore, we are at $dest and can output this path.

hope it helps. took some time to debug. let me know if it does not work for any case.

```
<?php

class Cubicle
{
    public $col;
    public $row;

    public function branch(Cubicle $dest)
    {
        $result = array();

        // move up
        if ($this->row > $dest->row)
            $result[] = new Cubicle($this->col, $this->row - 1);

        // move down
        elseif ($this->row < $dest->row)
            $result[] = new Cubicle($this->col, $this->row + 1);

        // move right
        if ($this->col < $dest->col)
        {
            // right-up
            if ($this->row >= $dest->row)
                $result[] = new Cubicle($this->col + 1, $this->row);

            // right-down
            else
                $result[] = new Cubicle($this->col + 1, $this->row - 1);
        }

        // move left
        elseif ($this->col > $dest->col)
        {
            // left-up
            if ($this->row > $dest->row)
                $result[] = new Cubicle($this->col - 1, $this->row - 1);

            // left-down
            else
                $result[] = new Cubicle($this->col - 1, $this->row);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function __construct($col, $row)
    {
        $this->col = $col;
        $this->row = $row;
    }
}

class Path
{
    public $cubicles = array();

    public function __construct(Cubicle $start)
    {
        $this->cubicles[] = $start;
    }

    public function getLast()
    {
        return $this->cubicles[count($this->cubicles)-1];
    }

    public function append($nextCubicle)
    {
        $clone = clone $this;
        $clone->cubicles[] = $nextCubicle;
        return $clone;
    }
}

function walk(Cubicle $start, Cubicle $dest) {
    $process = array(new Path($start));
    $output = array();

    while(count($process) > 0)
    {
        $currentPath = array_pop($process);

        $branches = $currentPath->getLast()->branch($dest);

        if (count($branches) == 0)
            $output[] = $currentPath;

        foreach ($branches as $branch)
            $process[] = $currentPath->append($branch);
    }

    return $output;
}

$start = new Cubicle(4, 6);
$dest = new Cubicle(5, 5);


$paths = walk($start, $dest);
var_dump($paths);
?>
```

outputs

```
array
  0 => 
    object(Path)[8]
      public 'cubicles' => 
        array
          0 => 
            object(Cubicle)[1]
              public 'col' => int 4
              public 'row' => int 6
          1 => 
            object(Cubicle)[5]
              public 'col' => int 5
              public 'row' => int 6
          2 => 
            object(Cubicle)[3]
              public 'col' => int 5
              public 'row' => int 5
  1 => 
    object(Path)[9]
      public 'cubicles' => 
        array
          0 => 
            object(Cubicle)[1]
              public 'col' => int 4
              public 'row' => int 6
          1 => 
            object(Cubicle)[4]
              public 'col' => int 4
              public 'row' => int 5
          2 => 
            object(Cubicle)[7]
              public 'col' => int 5
              public 'row' => int 5
```

this is a very inefficient approach because if you have overlapping paths, the algorithm will recalculate parts of those paths for each of the path. if you want a nicely performing algorithm, you will need to create some kind of graph, which contains only valid paths and depth-first search it for outputting all possible paths.